# Why will following sql-statement not work with JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am programming a basic database management system in java. When the user submits his username and password, the program will search in a database of the submitted data is correct:

```
    result = stat.executeUpdate("SELECT username,password FROM DB" + "WHERE (username = '"+loginusr.getText()+"',password = '"+loginpwd.getText()+"')");
```

Apparently there is an error near the = sign. Can someone help figuring this out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of issues there.

First, you need a space before the `WHERE`:

```
result = stat.executeUpdate("SELECT username,password FROM DB" + "WHERE (username = '"+loginusr.getText()+"',password = '"+loginpwd.getText()+"')");
// Here ---------------------------------------------------------^
```

But the more fundamental issue is that you've left that code wide open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks and failures. Use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), don't concatenate strings to put your parameters in. Here's a nice illustration of why:

[image]

From: http://xkcd.com/327/

And finally: It's not best practice to store passwords in a database. Instead, typically you store a cryptographic hash of the password, not the password itself ([SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha-256) is one hashing technique, for instance). Then when the user is authenticating, you hash what they gave you as their password and compare it with the hash you have stored. That way, the password cannot be retrieved from the database.

Comment: +1. Perhaps you should also add a remark about better not storing plain text passwords in the database.

Comment: I _have to_ upvote because the illustration really made my day :D

Comment: @Axel: Oh, wow, I didn't even read the statement that far. Yeah, on it.

Comment: Thanks all for the helpfull tips.
It's my first time with JDBC and databases in general, so the first iteration is just a basic draft as introduction.
Illustration was awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the general advice not to use string concatenation for SQL queries, but parameters instead, there is a mistake in the source: `…DB" + "WHERE…`  has no space.

Answer (score 1):

Your text expands to:

```
SELECT username,password FROM DBWHERE (username = ...
```

You need to add a space in to your string and use `AND` rather than `,`, e.g.:

```
result = stat.executeUpdate("SELECT username,password FROM DB " +
    "WHERE (username = '"+loginusr.getText()+"' AND password = '"+loginpwd.getText()+"')");
```

**However**, bear in mind that if this is an example of real code, there are at least two major security issues that should also be addressed.